# ROS Jade Installation Issues

Tags: ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I attempted to install ROS jade following the standard [installation instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu).

When trying to run  `sudo apt-get update` I encountered the following error with the key signing:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://packages.osrfoundation.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 67170598AF249743

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.osrfoundation.org/drc/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
```

Also, after trying to run `sudo apt-get install ros-jade-desktop-full` I got the following error:

```
Err http://packages.osrfoundation.org/drc/ubuntu/ trusty/main gazebo5-common all 5.1.0-1~trusty
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.osrfoundation.org/drc/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gazebo5/gazebo5-common_5.1.0-1~trusty_all.deb  404  Not Found
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.2 and currently have Indigo installed.

Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212984/ros-jade-installation-issues/) by [malvaradoCRL](https://answers.ros.org/users/20950/malvaradocrl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you imported the key ([Section 1.3 - Set up your keys](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu#jade.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-Sources.Set_up_your_keys))? And did that complete successfully?

---

Edit: looking at [Install Gazebo using Ubuntu packages - Step-by-step Install](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&ver=5.0&cat=install), the OSRF Gazebo package repositories have their own key, so you probably need to also run

```
wget http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

before trying to install Gazebo 5.

---

Edit 2:

> I attempted to install ROS jade following the standard installation instructions.

and

> I am running Ubuntu 14.04.2 and currently have Indigo installed.

Know that currently installing both Indigo and Jade on the same system will result in some difficulty, see [Gazebo version collides between Indigo and Jade](http://answers.ros.org/question/208334/gazebo-version-collides-between-indigo-and-jade/), especially when trying to install Gazebo 5.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [malvaradoCRL](https://answers.ros.org/users/20950/malvaradocrl/) on 2015-07-07**:
The key setup did work properly. The repo which was causing errors was an old DRC repository. I removed it from /etc/apt/sources.list.d and resolved the error.

After rebooting my machine and running apt-get autoremove and apt-get autoclean I was able to successfully install ros-jade-desktop-full.